# MySQL COUNT problem

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can count how many ungraded essays there are to be displayed? IF so What else do I have to add or take away from my MySQL code?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Here is my MySQL code.

```
SELECT students.*, students_essays.*  
FROM students  
INNER JOIN students_essays ON students.student_id = students_essays.student_id 
LEFT JOIN essays_grades ON students_essays.id = essays_grades.students_essays_id
WHERE essays_grades.grade_id IS NULL
ORDER BY students_essays.id DESC;
```

Here is my MySQL tables.

```
CREATE TABLE students_essays (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
content TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE students (
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
student_first_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
student_last_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);


CREATE TABLE essays_grades (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
grade_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
students_essays_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE grades (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
letter_grade VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
grade_points FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Count per student or in total?

Comment: I just want to count how many ungraded essays there are total in the database.

Comment: Just a comment on your table structure. Is it ever possible for an essay to have more than one grade? If not, there is no reason to have the `essays_grades` table... you could just store the `grade_id` directly in the `students_essays` table. This will make your queries a bit easier going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you only need to look at 2 tables for this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students_essays se
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM 
                 essays_grades ge
                 WHERE se.id = eg.students_essays_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*)  
FROM students  
INNER JOIN students_essays ON students.student_id = students_essays.student_id 
LEFT JOIN essays_grades ON students_essays.id = essays_grades.students_essays_id
WHERE essays_grades.grade_id IS NULL
ORDER BY students_essays.id DESC;
```

Comment: IIRC, the asterisk in `COUNT(*)` is where one needs to pay attention: `COUNT(grade_id)` would not count `NULL` rows, while `COUNT(*)` does.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but drop the order by if the count is all that is required (wasted operation)